# Difference between alphabet $a$ and "a"

Tags: symbols

I have a very simple problem.
I want to write "a" in an equation, however output is .... Please see output.
How i can overcome this problem?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It looks like you are using a language package that redefines the arabic digits. Can you show us an example that reproduces the screenshot you get, please? In any way what you are typing should definitely be written in math mode: `$A = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$`

Comment: Please see "a" carefully. The problem is there.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439880/35864

Comment: Solved in comments in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439880/diffrece-between-a-and-a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Diffrece between "a" and $a$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439880/diffrece-between-a-and-a)