# Difference between "a" and $a$

Tags: symbols

I have a very simple problem. I want to write "a" in an equation, however output is .... Please see output.
Please see "a" carefully, the problem is there.
How i can overcome this problem?[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You need to provide us the short code you used to generate this output.  Then, the answer will be directly at hand.  Perhaps you want `\mathrm{a}` for `a` instead of *`a`*.

Comment: How is this question different from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439875/35864 apart from the subscripts? Please show us the code that produces this. And please explain what you want to write. The second picture does not use bold 'a's. Do you want `\mathbf{a}`?

Comment: Of course I see the difference in the two outputs. **But what is the question?** Do you want the first and can only get the second? Do you want the second and can only get the first?

Comment: I have the second and want to get the first.

Comment: well you want `\mathbf{a}_1` but there would be _no way_ to guess that was what you wanted from your question without the comment that you just added,

Comment: OK, please consider adding the actual question to your question in future. The question is extremely unclear without the additional explanation. Asking the same question twice in short succession instead of editing the first question is normally discouraged. And you can make it much easier for other people to help you if you include an minimal working example of the code that produced the output you get, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). The MWE was not vital to understanding your question, but sometimes it is.

Comment: ... And an MWE can often help people to get started helping you more quickly. Please have a look at the [TeX.SX welcome site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/35864).

Comment: Why did you ask the same question again?? Just edit your original question.